# Trigger to capture screenshot if specific text appear on screen

Tags: text, autoit

Is there any solution for this issue that trigger to capture screenshot if specific text appear on screen?
E.g. Need to watch my screen if “NeedToCapture” appear on screen take screenshot, and contine till i stop it.

I try Autoit but it wont have realtime text detection.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Only way I can thing of: take periodically screenshots and convert to text via OCR (when you find the text, you even already have a screenshot...)

Comment: @Stephan Need realtime solution.

Comment: Might depend on the application that shows the message. What is it? A Browser? A command line app? Is the text readable (are you able to copy it and paste it somewhere else)?

Comment: @Stephan Outlook 2016, status of user

Comment: Outlook has no own "user status" (assuming you mean Available/Busy/OffWork/...). It gets that information from Lync/Skype/Teams(/etc?) There is an Outlook UDF, but I doubt, it can access this info.

Answer (score 0):

“NeedToCapture” is on the web page or one desktop applicaiton?
you can refer to the following sample code:

```
import os
from clicknium import clicknium as cc, locator, ui

elem = cc.wait_appear(locator.app.element, wait_timeout=300)
if elem != None:
    file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"screen.png")
    ui(locator.explorer.list_1).save_to_image(file_path)
```

locator.app.element and locator.explorer.list_1 can be recorded by clicknium recorder, you can find the extension from visual studio code extenion page.

for exampple, the locator of 'locator.explorer.list_1' similiar as the following:
[locator of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGjaB.png)

Comment: Outlook 2016, status of user